# How to get multiple most frequent k-mers of a string using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If I insert the following

```
Insert the Text:
ACACACA
Insert a value for k:
2
```

For the following codes

```
print("Insert the Text:")
Text = input()
print("Insert a value for k:")
k = int(input())
Pattern = " "
count = [ ]
FrequentPatterns = [ ]

def FrequentWords(Text, k):
    for i in range (len(Text)-k+1):
        Pattern = Text[i: i+k]
        c = 0
        for i in range (len(Text)-len(Pattern)+1):   
            if Text[i: i+len(Pattern)] == Pattern:
                c = c+1
            else: 
                continue
        count.extend([c])
    print(count)
    if count[i] == max(count):   
        FrequentPatterns.extend([Pattern])
    return  FrequentPatterns

FrequentWords(Text, k)
```

I get the following out put

```
Insert the Text:
ACACACA
Insert a value for k:
2
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
['CA']
```

Clearly there are two `FrequentPatterns`. So the last list output should be `['AC', 'CA']`
I don't know why this code isn't working. Really appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: Just to clarify the terminology: You want to count the distinct, overlapping consecutive letter sequences of length 2 from the input string?

Comment: @Tomalak, Yes, Exactly! But not just any distinct letter sequence of length 2 but the most frequent one. Here for example, the sequence is "ACACACA". "AC" appeared 3 times and "CA" appeared 3 times. So both are most frequent. If I had "ACTGAC". Then there will be one most frequent 2 letter sequence which is "AC".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how would solve this:

```
from itertools import groupby

def find_kgrams(string, k):
    kgrams = sorted(
        string[j:j+k]
            for i in range(k)
                for j in range(i, (len(string) - i) // k * k, k)
    )
    groups = [(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(kgrams)]
    return sorted(groups, key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)
```

The way this works is:

- it produces string chunks of the given length `k`, e.g.:

  - starting from 0: 'ACACACA' -> 'AC', 'AC', 'AC'
  - starting from 1: 'ACACACA' -> 'CA', 'CA', 'CA'
  - ...up to `k - 1` (1 is the maximum for `k == 2`)
- `groupby()` groups those chunks
- `sorted()` sorts them by count
- a list of tuples of kgrams and their count is returned

Test:

```
s = 'ACACACA'
kgrams = find_kgrams(s, 2)
print(kgrams)
```

prints:

```
[('AC', 3), ('CA', 3)]
```

It's already sorted, you can pick the most frequent one(s) from the front of the returned list:

```
max_kgrams = [k for k, s in kgrams if s == kgrams[1][1])
print(max_kgrams)
```

prints:

```
['AC', 'CA']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that! I understood and it's working. Just wanted to ask, were you able to figure out what the problem was in my codes? I still don't understand why it did not work.

Comment: @incrediblesulk Your code only outputs the last pattern (here `'CA'`) because you're appending to `FrequentPatterns` only once, after the main loop. You should to that once per found pattern. Overall your nested loop approach is needlessly inefficient, you're going over the string way too often. I would expect this to slow down significantly for large inputs.

Comment: @incrediblesulk I've made another major change to the function. I didn't pay attention to the fact that `groupby()` requires pre-sorted input.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you. My codes were not efficiently written. Actually, it was an exercise from a Bioinformatics textbook written for those with limited programming knowledge. The authors provided a pseudocode and wanted the reader to write actual codes and see for themselves that this isn't an efficient way of doing it